# OFDM does not work with USRP

Tags: modulation, ofdm, gnuradio, usrp

I found the ofdm flowchart in the Gnu radio examples.(ofdm_loopback)

Scheme:
[image]

The spectrum and the received data of the received signal:
[image]

After that, I connect the USRP Sink and the USRP Source.

[image]

The spectrum and the received data of the received signal(USRP):
[image]

A similar question has already been encountered [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70584721/ofdm-sysetm-with-usrp-implemntation) but, unfortunately, the answers did not help to understand the cause of the problem.

Why is this happening and what settings do I need to enable to solve this problem?

Comment: Can someone say what a USRP is?  It's not even defined in the tag.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson USRP is Software Defined Radio. It's not a tag. Bloсks USRP Source and USRP Sink define transmission parameters: frequency, gain and ets. Perhaps these blocks should somehow match the OFDM parameters.